# Random not getting its max value

Tags: c#, random, console

I am trying to create a console application which is basically a very simple version of a security measure used by some websites and banks etc.

The user will have declared a "Secret Word"(stored in a stringBuilder), after which, every time the user tries to access the program/website etc they have to enter character X of the word (X generated via a random). However, the random never selects the last character of the word.

Example: When i use a 2 letter Secret word, it will only ever select the first letter, when i have tried getting it to select the letter by other methods it thinks that there is a letter 0 which throws the whole application.

Why is the final character never being selected? please help (new to c#)

Code Below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

       namespace randomCharSelecter
       {
            class Program
           {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Secret Word");
                    stringBuilder.Append(Console.ReadLine());           


                    EnterInput:
                    Random rndSelect = new Random();
                    int randomChar1 = rndSelect.Next(1, (stringBuilder.Length));

                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter character {0} of your secret word", randomChar1);
                    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (userInput == (Convert.ToString(stringBuilder).Substring(randomChar1 - 1, 1)))
                        Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect! Please try again");
                        goto EnterInput;
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value
> Type: System.Int32
>
> A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to *minValue* and **less than *maxValue***; that is, the range of return values includes *minValue* but not *maxValue*. If *minValue* equals *maxValue*, *minValue* is returned.

In other words if you want a random integer between 1 and `stringBuilder.Length`, inclusive (that is, that the result could possibly equal `stringBuilder.Length`), you need to use:

```
int randomChar1 = rndSelect.Next(1, stringBuilder.Length + 1);
```

*Alternatively*, you could simply modify the code to make use of [zero-based indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering):

```
int randomChar1 = rndSelect.Next(0, stringBuilder.Length);
...
if (userInput == (Convert.ToString(stringBuilder).Substring(randomChar1, 1)))
    Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
```

Comment: Oh i see now, Thanks so much works like a charm, knew i was missing something :)

Comment: @KLM Messages you display to the user and values you use to represent data internally are frequently different. Personally, I'd prefer the zero-based indexing approach because C#/.NET uses zero-based indexing natively, and I'd rather tweak the display value just for the benefit of the user. But both solutions are valid. Use whichever you're more comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i can see why zero-based would be preferable and will correct my code accordingly, thank you for your input.

Comment: @p-s-w-g
 Yeah just went over the code and changed it to zero-based, looks much cleaner, once again thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the second value of `Random.Next(int val1, int val2)` is **end-exclusive**. So you'll end up having to do `stringBuilder.Length + 1`

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx